# argument of type 'ManyToManyDescriptor' is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have mode:

```
class Subscribe(models.Model):
   class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'sunscribes'

   id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   name=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=False);

   owner=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='owner', null=False, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   subscription = models.ManyToManyField(User,null=True,related_name='subscription')
```

I need to select all Subscribe items  where this user is in the list subscration

My attempt:

```
avtor=post.author # user item
subscribe=Subscribe.objects.get(avtor in Subscribe.subscription ) # get list
```

Error:
argument of type 'ManyToManyDescriptor' is not iterable

Post is instance of Article:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Comment: Related Name is not required with M2M field.    `subscription = models.ManyToManyField(User,null=True,related_name='subscription')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse relations use the name you define in `related_name`, so to get all the subscriptions for a user is simply

```
avtor.subscription.all()
```

Your error message comes from

```
avtor in Subscribe.subscription
```

which doesn't really make sense.. To start from `Subscribe` you would need to do

```
Subscribe.objects.filter(subscription__user=avtor)
```